# How to know the theme name of a wordpress blog?

Tags: themes

I visit http://ltty.wordpress.com/ and want to know the theme name (so that I can use :) for my blog). How can I get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method isn't always fireproof, but you can often look at the source code (right click on white space in the blog), and look for the word "themes." For instance, in the case of ltty.wordpress.com, this line appears:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s2.wp.com/wp-content/themes/pub/inove/style.css?m=1285721595g" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

The theme is "inove." A quick Google Search reveals this source:
 http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/inove

Answer (score 2):

This is WordPress **.com** blog - running on provided service. It has no installable themes but choice from number of themes, provided by service. I can't find official list of themes available there so no idea if there is version for self-hosted blogs available.

For self-hosted version of WordPress (commonly referred to as **.org**) you can usually find theme name by looking up and opening `style.css` file in source.